# UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification received after applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground test passed

Tags: objective-c, uikit, grand-central-dispatch

I am writing an Objective-C wrapper for using a GCD timer source. One of the goals is for the wrapper to manage suspending the timer source when the application enters the background.

The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW20) for `-[UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:]` indicate that it should be used to invalidate timers, among other things; I'm interpreting this somewhat loosely (perhaps that is the source of my problem?) in that I'm suspending a GCD timer (`dispatch_suspend()`) in response to `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`).

When an instance of the wrapper is initialized, it checks `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground` to determine whether the GCD timer source should initially be resumed as part of the initialization sequence. It also registers for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` which it uses to suspend and resume the timer source (respectively).

The issue that I have observed is that there seem to be cases where the check of `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground` during initialization is passed so that the timer source is resumed, ***and*** the next notification that is received is `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` which causes the timer source to be resumed a second time. This leads to a crash since the timer was not suspended at the time of the second resume.

I can work around this by keeping track of the application state locally and confirming the transitions that would be duplicate, but I am concerned that I may be doing something incorrectly or that there may be a bug (either in implementation or in documentation).

Comment: I should also note that at this time I do not have a reproducible test case to reliably demonstrate this issue.

Comment: Filed as rdar://12892621 and http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2444401

Comment: Still hoping to get an authoritative answer on this one. I'll update when/if I get more info in response to the bug report I filed.

Answer (score 2):

This is how app state works:

On initial Launch,

1. application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
2. applicationDidBecomeActive

When you hit the home button,

1. applicationWillResignActive
2. applicationDidEnterBackground

When you open a backgrounded app,

1. applicationWillEnterForeground
2. applicationDidBecomeActive

Opening - (initial launch and opening backgrounded app) - applicationDidBecomeActive gets called - initialize timer here.

Hiding or receiving call, etc - applicationWillResignActive gets called - stop timer here.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the UIApplication docs:

```
UIApplicationStateInactive
The application is running in the foreground but is not receiving events. 
This might happen as a result of an interruption or because the application
is transitioning to or from the background.
```

So it's possible that your app was in Background, will soon be in Foreground, but is currently transitioning.

Comment: In that case, if the application state is UIApplicationStateInactive, then I believe the UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification should have already been posted.

Comment: I believe that too, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

So here's something you can do to get a better picture of what's going on:

In your apps main.m, add this:

```
 @interface GTTestObject : NSObject

 - (void)logNotification:(id)sender;
 @end

 @implementation GTTestObject

 - (void)logNotification:(id)sender {

     NSLog(@"%@", [(NSNotification *)sender name]);

 }
 @end


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     @autoreleasepool {

         // I'm assuming you'd be using ARC...
         GTTestObject *obj = [[GTTestObject alloc] init];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:obj selector:@selector(logNotification:) name:nil object:nil];

         return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([GTAppDelegate class]));
     }
 }
```

Then for every `MyAppDelegate.m` method "...didFinishLaunching, ...didEnterBackground, etc." add this:

```
     NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

Now you'll be able to see the sequence, time-stamp and (possibly) any conflicts with notification/delegate calls occurring simultaneously.

It's possible you'll get slightly different results from test to test, so run it several times to be sure.

For an example run, I see this every time:

```
 2012-12-21 08:13:58.559 Gamerton[34158:c07] [GTAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] state: UIApplicationStateInactive
 2012-12-21 08:13:58.560 Gamerton[34158:c07] UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification state: UIApplicationStateInactive

 ...

 2012-12-21 08:13:58.561 Gamerton[34158:c07] [GTAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] state: UIApplicationStateActive
 2012-12-21 08:13:58.561 Gamerton[34158:c07] UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification state: UIApplicationStateActive

 ... Hit home button

 2012-12-21 08:16:08.227 Gamerton[34170:c07] [GTAppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] state: UIApplicationStateActive
 2012-12-21 08:16:08.228 Gamerton[34170:c07] UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification state: UIApplicationStateActive
 2012-12-21 08:16:08.229 Gamerton[34170:c07] UIApplicationSuspendedNotification state: UIApplicationStateBackground
 2012-12-21 08:16:08.229 Gamerton[34170:c07] [GTAppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:] state: UIApplicationStateBackground

 ... Reopen app

 2012-12-21 08:16:59.364 Gamerton[34170:c07] [GTAppDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground:] state: UIApplicationStateBackground
 2012-12-21 08:16:59.365 Gamerton[34170:c07] UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification state: UIApplicationStateBackground
 2012-12-21 08:16:59.365 Gamerton[34170:c07] _UIApplicationDidRemoveDeactivationReasonNotification
 2012-12-21 08:16:59.366 Gamerton[34170:c07] [GTAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] state: UIApplicationStateActive
 2012-12-21 08:16:59.366 Gamerton[34170:c07] UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification state: UIApplicationStateActive
 2012-12-21 08:16:59.366 Gamerton[34170:c07] UIApplicationResumedNotification state: UIApplicationStateActive
 2012-12-21 08:16:08.230 Gamerton[34170:c07] UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification state: UIApplicationStateActive
```